# How to Fix Spanish Numbers

Tags: java

What I have to do is to create a SpanishNumbers application that displays numbers 1 through 10 in Spanish. A method with an int parameter should display the Spanish word for the number passed. A loop structure in the main() method should be used to call the method ten times. The Spanish word equivalents for numbers 1 through 10 are...

1 uno 2 dos, 3 tres, 4 cuatro, 5 cinco, 6 seis, 7 siete, 8 ocho, 9 nueve, 10 diez.

I do not know why am I getting this error below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLIiI.png

Thanks in advanced!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class SpanishNumberss {

        public static void spanishNumbers(int num) {

            String[] numbers = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve", "diez"};
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                System.out.println(numbers[num]);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) { 

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
                spanishNumbers(i); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you just want to print each number once, then you don't need that extra `for` loop in your `spanishNumbers` method. Just have the `System.out.println` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayIndexOutOfBounds means you have gone out of the boundaries of your array (in your case `numbers`).  What you have to realize is array's are 0 index-based.  So in your `for` loop, you really 0 - 9, not 1-10.

And an even better solution, as @rgettman has posted is to use the length property of the array. So you are not hard-coding in those magic numbers.

Comment: Fixed I just had to change from for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) { to for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {

Comment: @user3362775 ok, not sure what I was replying to... aren't you still printing `uno, dos, dos, tres, tres, tres...`?

Comment: yeah uno
dos
dos
tres
tres
tres
cuatro
cuatro
cuatro
cuatro
cinco
cinco
cinco
cinco
cinco
seis
seis
seis
seis
seis
seis
siete
siete
siete
siete
siete
siete
siete
ocho
ocho
ocho
ocho
ocho
ocho
ocho
ocho
nueve
nueve
nueve
nueve
nueve
nueve
nueve
nueve
nueve
diez
diez
diez
diez
diez
diez
diez
diez
diez
diez

Comment: @user3362775 ok, just assumed you may have wanted `uno, dos, tres, ...` Glad it's working the way you want!

Answer (score 3):

In Java, indexes of an array start with `0`, not `1`, and run through `length - 1`, not `length`.

Adjust your `for` loop condition in `main` as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
```

You'll need to adjust your other `for` loop similarly.

Comment: Well that is not at all correct..`You'll need to adjust your other for loop similarly.` based on what he said he don't need at all a second for

Answer (score 2):

Arrays indexes are 0 based (**starts from 0 not from 1**) . Also you are declaring your array `numbers` inside the method each time is called just declare as a class variable. So take care that in your example index 0 refers to 1 (uno) and so on.

I made you an example and add `0,"cero"`

```
public class SpanishNumberss {

  private static final  String[] numbers = {"cero","uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve", "diez"};

        public static void spanishNumbers(int num) {    
             //loop here is unnecesary 
             System.out.println(numbers[num]);                
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) { 
            //and here in main i call them from 1 to 10
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++){ 
                spanishNumbers(i); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays go from 0 to N-1

That's why you're getting that error, change your for cycle to:

```
       for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[num]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
```

Arrays in Java are `0`-based. So the valid indices run from `0` to `array.length - 1`. So an array of length `5` would have the valid indices `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. Change your loop to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

This will ensure that in your loop `i` will only have the values from `0` to `9`.

Answer (score 0):

your loop should only have the values from **0 to 9**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all i don't think you need a loop in the spanishnumber method...

cos you already know the index of what you are looking...// that's if i understand you

so the only place you need the loop is in the main method...so your code should look like dis

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        spanishNumbers(6);
    }
}

public static void spanishNumbers(int num) {

    String[] numbers = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve", "diez"};
    System.out.println(numbers[num -1]);
}
```